# RSA C++ equivalent in C#

Tags: c++, rsa

I have been trying to just get the equivalent of this C# code in C++ for a couple days now, and it's not working out.

Here is my C# code:

```
RSAParameters rsaParams = new RSAParameters();
rsaParams.Modulus = someByteArray;
rsaParams.Exponent = someByteArray1;
rsaParams.D = someByteArray2;
rsaParams.DP = someByteArray3;
rsaParams.DQ = someByteArray4;
rsaParams.P = someByteArray5;
rsaParams.Q = someByteArray6;
rsaParams.InverseQ = someByteArray7;

using (RSACryptoServiceProvider rsa = new RSACryptoServiceProvider())
{
    rsa.ImportParameters(rsaParams);
    byte[] encryptedData = rsa.Encrypt(toEncrypt, false);
}
```

I want to just have the same exact results, but in C++ (cross platform). I have looked at many libraries/classes, but they don't seem resonable. First of all, Crypto++ is great and all, but all I want is RSA, so having all of their hashing/encryption/whatever else algorithms is just a waste as I look at it. I found [this](http://code.google.com/p/rsa/) class, which I thought was good because it is only RSA and is pretty small. The problem is, is that the parameters either aren't named the same as the C# ones, or it doesn't support it. I feel like I shouldn't have to learn what each parameter means in RSA just to implement it, as I just want to complete a simple task here. Thanks.

Comment: Is the reason you need the same parameters because you have a front end in C# and a back end in C++?

Comment: No it's because I was just testing some stuff with C#, and my application will be in C++, so I just need to transfer it over.

Comment: Since the RSA encryption you are using includes random padding you will never get the exact same results even if you have succeeded in implementing a correct, compatible C++ version. Furthermore, only the first two fields (Modulus and Exponent) are needed or used for RSA *encryption*.

Comment: Alright, thank you. But let's say I do only want to use the modulus and exponent. How could I generate the other ones, because if I take the other ones away (in C#), it throw a "Bad Key." error.

Answer (score 2):

The properties of the RSAParameters struct are based on the [Chinese Remainder Algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RSA_%28algorithm%29#Using_the_Chinese_remainder_algorithm).
Have you looked at the [OpenSSL](http://www.openssl.org/docs/crypto/rsa.html#) crypto library?

> The RSA structure consists of several BIGNUM components. It can
>   contain public as well as private RSA keys:

```
struct
    {
    BIGNUM *n;              // public modulus
    BIGNUM *e;              // public exponent
    BIGNUM *d;              // private exponent
    BIGNUM *p;              // secret prime factor
    BIGNUM *q;              // secret prime factor
    BIGNUM *dmp1;           // d mod (p-1)
    BIGNUM *dmq1;           // d mod (q-1)
    BIGNUM *iqmp;           // q^-1 mod p
    // ...
    };
RSA
```

Comment: Why do I feel like it's difficult to setup? I downloaded the latest from http://www.openssl.org/source/, and I try including the 'rsa.h' from the includes folder which results in errors... I must be missing a huge part here.

Comment: If you have OpenSSL question try asking here or on [OpenSSL Support, Mailing lists](http://www.openssl.org/support/community.html)

Comment: @hetelek: Look at the `apps/rsa.c` source for an example. The function you want is `RSA_public_encrypt()` and the padding should be RSA_PKCS1_PADDING which is #defined as 1.